# Trouble iterating over an array to populate google ecommerce tracking

Tags: php, zend-framework, foreach

Ok so I have this array that I want to use to populate gaq ecommerce tracking:

```
$ga_itemdata = Array ( [0] => Array ( [product_id] => 7 [prod_name] => Pet Driver's License Bag Tag [prod_count] => 2 [price] => 19.99 ) [1] => Array ( [product_id] => 6 [prod_name] => The Driver's License Pet Tag [prod_count] => 1 [price] => 19.99 ) [2] => Array ( [product_id] => 5 [prod_name] => Pet Driver's License Key Chain [prod_count] => 3 [price] => 19.99 ) [3] => Array ( [product_id] => 4 [prod_name] => Pet Driver's License Magnet [prod_count] => 2 [price] => 14.99 ) [4] => Array ( [product_id] => 3 [prod_name] => Pet Driver's License Wallet Card [prod_count] => 3 [price] => 19.99 ) )
```

Im trying to populate the following code with these variables then echo to the page, once for each item in the array:

```
_gaq.push(['_addItem',
$order_id,         // I have this from another array
$product_id,       // SKU/code
$prod_name,        // product name
'empty',           // category or variation
$price',           // unit price
$prod_count        // quantity
]);
```

I have this foreach loop:

```
foreach($ga_itemdata as $itemnum => $itemarr[0]) {
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($itemarr); $i++){
    foreach ($itemarr[$i] as $details[$i]) {

            // echo google tracking code 
          }
      }
     }
```

It doesnt seem so be working right and im stuck on it, any help would be awesome!

Comment: you asked this once already, add a bounty if you want more answers

Comment: Not a duplicate, I have the array the way I want it. Having trouble iterating over it. I can't set a bounty for 2 days.